# EF6 - Using the await keyword with the Where() clause

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, where-clause, async-await

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application with entity framework 6 and have a question in regards to using the `await` keyword when using the `.Where()` clause.

Here is my code that works:

```
public async Task<Account> GetAccount(string userName)
{
    if (Session[userName] == null)
    {
        Account account = db.accounts.Where(a => a.userName.Equals(userName)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (account == null)
        {
            //log out
            return null;
        }
        Session[userName] = account;
    }
    return Session[userName] as Account;
}
```

I am wanting to use the await keyword when retrieving the `Account object` as follows:

```
Account account = await db.accounts.Where(a => a.userName.Equals(userName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can the `await` keyword be used when using the `.Where()` clause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The await keyword can only be used on methods that return "Task...", neither `.Where` nor `.FirstOrDefault` (Which is the last method in the chain, and thus would be the one the await keyword would apply to) return `Task<IEnumerable<Account>>`

In theory you could write you own extension method which simply wraps around the `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault` methods.

Also, this question isn't exactly EF specific, but rather a 'pure' C# question.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhereAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> selector)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => source.Where(selector));
    }
}
```

Although that would be kind of overkill imho.

You could just wrap your entire method in a Task, so your final code would be something like:

```
public async Task<Account> GetAccount(string userName)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (Session[userName] == null)
        {
            Account account = db.accounts.Where(a => a.userName.Equals(userName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (account == null)
            {
                //log out
                return null;
            }
            Session[userName] = account;
        }
        return Session[userName] as Account;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 16):

There is no `WhereAsync()` method provided by EF (obviously because it can't potentially block, since LINQ uses deferred-execution), but since you're performing a `FirstOrDefault()`
you could simply use the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` method:

```
Account account = await db.accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.userName.Equals(userName));
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx)